# Air regulation. About QNH , TA and TL

Tags: cpl

[image]
What is the TL here ? How to calculate this ???

Comment: Transition Level, is the altitude where you switch from standard pressure to the altimeter setting while in descent.

Comment: There has to be more to the question than what is shown?  What is the standard transition level over Mumbai?

Comment: Please enter the text into your question instead of depending on screenshots.  People using accessibility services may not be able to read text within screenshots.  Thanks!

Comment: Questions in the format of "answer my homework question" showing no effort on the part of the OP are not appropriate on Aviation.SE.